# how to assign two tablespaces to a single user?

Tags: database, oracle

is there a way to assign two tablespace to a single user example: vehiculelocation for user and TableLocationVehicule, TableLocationVehicul1 for tablespaces respectively ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a default tablespace for a user, not 2. And that does not mean that no other user can use this tablespace, it is just that if you create a table or an index without specifying a tablespace, it will go into the default one. Otherwise, you can say for each table/index in which tablespace it should go.

Comment: i found a way that worked for me : `-- Create two tablespaces
SQL> create tablespace meta_data datafile size 1m;

Tablespace created.

SQL> create tablespace data datafile size 1m;

Tablespace created.


SQL> create user user1 identified by user1 quota unlimited on meta_data
  2  ;

User created.
SQL> alter user user1 identified by user1 quota unlimited on data;

User altered.

--Now, the user can create objects on both of the tablespaces
`